# How can I install Unity 3D game engine for Ubuntu?

Tags: unity3d

I wish to develop some games on Unity 3D game engine. I was unable to find the link to download the application. Can someone post the download link for Unity 3D game engine for Ubuntu and/or explain how to install it?

Comment: Have you even tried searching on Google for Unity Game Engine Linux? Here are the links: [blog post](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/08/26/unity-comes-to-linux-experimental-build-now-available/) and the forum posts containing the links to [beta releases](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/#post-3220320).

Answer (score 10):

The below link used in the `wget` command can be retrieved [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256) and **is subject to change over time**. At the time of writing this was the actual link and the procedure is tested in Ubuntu 17.10 and 16.04 but should as well work in lower versions of Ubuntu. If not you might want to consider upgrading.

---

As well you want at least 15-20 GB free space on your HDD/SSD for this operation. Now that this all is out of the way do the following in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
wget http://beta.unity3d.com/download/ee86734cf592/unity-editor_amd64-2017.2.0f3.deb
sudo gdebi unity-editor_amd64-2017.2.0f3.deb
```

Comment: The latest one, 2018.1.0b8 (pro license), completely crashes on Ubuntu 17.10 when building an Android project. I'm trying it with older versions now...

Comment: Thanks! A great guideline!. 

worked on `Ubuntu 14.04.3`

P.S.

Seems that `.deb`'s download is *kind a throttled*.
i'v got max, `~900KB/s` for a download using`wget` from several origins, that have much higher requirements for a download channel :)

Comment: You can try to download it from the link mentioned at the top of my answer via Firefox/Chrome, I'm merely a terminal jockey so I give my answers according to that. Despite I had no throttling as I tried this.

Comment: The deb archive in this answer is now four years old. Please see other recent answers.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2020 Unity has released the stable version UnityHub for Linux. TO install Unity Engine you need to

1. Download the AppImage from [Unity3D](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download).
2. Make the AppImage executable.

```
chmod +x UnityHub.AppImage
```

3. Execute the AppImage.

```
./UnityHub.AppImage
```

4. Now SignIn through UnityHub in preferences
5. Download and Install relevant platform packages.

Answer (score 2):

I did it by downloading .deb file (Debian Package) from the last link [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-on-linux-release-notes-and-known-issues.350256/) (Official Installers) and then just run it with Software Install. Don't forget to restart the machine before use.

Answer (score 1):

We can install unity hub on ubuntu and after that the unity, link for the same is below - https://public-cdn.cloud.unity3d.com/hub/prod/UnityHubSetup.AppImage